# Matlab waiter "cancel" button won't respond

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

Im using the built-in Matlab **waitbar function**, and also using the built- in "CreateCancelBtn" option, which adds a cancel button (so I can cancel a for loop).

**The problem is, that when I'm pressing the "cancel" button, nothing happens**, but if I press the "X" button the process is canceled as it should (according to Matlab the "X" button is defined to act like the "cancel" button).

another fact: the problem is occurring only when I'm running the function (see below) from my project (a GUIDE UI), but when I run the code as a standalone, there is no issue.
Any ideas how to solve\track the problem?

A link to the waitbar function doc: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/waitbar.html

Here is the code im using (from mathworks documentation):

```
function approxpi

f = waitbar(0,'1','Name','Approximating pi...',...
    'CreateCancelBtn','setappdata(gcbf,''canceling'',1)');

setappdata(f,'canceling',0);

% Approximate pi^2/8 as: 1 + 1/9 + 1/25 + 1/49 + ...
pisqover8 = 1;
denom = 3;
valueofpi = sqrt(8 * pisqover8);

steps = 20000;
for step = 1:steps
    % Check for clicked Cancel button
    if getappdata(f,'canceling')
        break
    end

    % Update waitbar and message
    waitbar(step/steps,f,sprintf('%12.9f',valueofpi))

    % Calculate next estimate 
    pisqover8 = pisqover8 + 1 / (denom * denom);
    denom = denom + 2;
    valueofpi = sqrt(8 * pisqover8);
end

delete(f)
end
```

Comment: Your issue is not reproducible for me in R2018a

Comment: If this works itself, problem is elsewhere. Shows us your GUIDE structure and code. Maybe you have a problem with access correct element, for example you refer to not existing (overwrite) instance of waitbar.